# launchDaemon choose shared file location that doesn't require full disk access

Tags: launchd, accessibility, macos

I've got an mach-o executable that runs from launchDaemon plist file, and is communicating with other processes using unix domain socket. The file that backs this socket created in `/tmp`.
However, this cause the executable to fail reading the file unless given full disk access.

I'd like to find a location for the socket file, which is shared to all processes and doesn't require full disk access. the executable reside in /Library/Application Support/myProj/bin/exec_file

is there such location ? Perhaps can i use the same location of the executable itself ?